# Can we overwrite Filtered DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, automationstudio, triggered-send

We are importing data from CRM to a DE. What I want to do is to send out a welcome email to newly added subscribers on real time.
For this I have created a data filter using joindate = today on main DE and a filter activity in an automation which runs on every two hours to check new subscribers in the main DE. so that I can use that filtered DE to send welcome email but the result filtered DE can't seem to be overwritten. It is carrying previous data and then fresh data for present date after every two hours.

Can somebody help me with best practice to send welcome email to subscribers getting added to a DE in real time Via Journey or triggered send.

Answer (score 1):

A filtered data extension will ALWAYS overwrite when refreshed - as in, it will only hold records that meet the criteria at the time of refresh.

The reason you are seeing the same people still in there, is likely because your filter isn't accurate enough. You want people from the last two hours, but your filter is asking for everyone that joined today. So unless those two hours occurred before and after midnight, there is no reason for the filter to kick any of the previous people out.

Unfortunately filters don't go down to the hour - so I would suggest writing an SQL query. You can set the query to overwrite the results on each run, ensuring you are only bringing in the subscribers from the past hour, without keeping the older ones.

If you want *real-time* triggering, you will need either APIs, or use the default list welcome email functionality, or even Playbooks for a series of three emails (will send within 5 minutes of signup for the first email)

Comment: No problem - queries will definitely be your friend going forward